# Plugin to Check logged in user’s web role in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, plugins, portal, dynamics-crm-365, webrole

Please help me with this code. I am trying to create a plugin for Dynamics 365 portal to check the logged in user's web roles (`adx_webrole`) and if the user has role named "administrator", then update of the field "permissions" should be allowed, otherwise it should throw an error.

I am trying the following code. Even if I have the administrator web role, it throws error. So I believe my code is not fetching any web roles. Please help.

```
private bool UserHasWebRole(Guid userId, string webRoleName, IOrganizationService service)   
{     
    // Query to check if the user has the specified web role
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");    
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("contactid");    
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userId);    
    query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("adx_webrole", "adx_webrole_contact", "adx_webroleid", "contactid", JoinOperator.Inner));    
    query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("role", ConditionOperator.Equal, GetWebRoleId(webRoleName, service));

    EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    // If there are records, the user has the web role
    return result.Entities.Count > 0;  
}

private Guid GetWebRoleId(string webRoleName, IOrganizationService service)   
{     
    // Retrieve the web role ID based on its name
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("adx_webrole");
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("adx_webroleid");
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("adx_name", ConditionOperator.Equal, webRoleName);

    EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    // Check if the web role exists
    if (result.Entities.Count > 0)     
    {
        return result.Entities[0].Id;
    }    
    else     
    {
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException($"Web role '{webRoleName}' not found.");    
    }  
}
```